# How can I use Kalabox with a WordPress Install that has a nested web root?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, pantheon

I have been trying and failing for a week to get Kalabox working with a WordPress install that has a nested web root with Pantheon. I've found some great resources, but many of them are for Drupal and they don't seem to translate to the WP installs, like the great post by Tandem here: https://www.thinktandem.io/blog/2017/05/20/using-pantheon-s-nested-docroot-with-kalabox/

Does anyone have a quick walkthrough that would work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Here's what it took:

## 1. Setup A Site In [Pantheon](http://pantheon.io)

- [Create Sites](https://pantheon.io/docs/create-sites/)

## 2. Clone the Site to your local machine using [Kalabox](http://kalabox.io)

Make sure you've installed Kalabox on your machine. This will also install Docker, if you haven't already installed it. Now, open your terminal.

```
mkdir -p ~/Kalabox
cd ~/Kalabox
kbox create pantheon
# follow the prompts to clone down your Pantheon site
```

## 3. Add Your Site Code

This is where the real work starts. Make sure you're in the main Kalabox directory. I'm using the excellent [Advanced Wordpress On Pantheon](https://github.com/ataylorme/advanced-wordpress-on-pantheon.git) as the boilerplate for this app. But you can use whatever you'd like.

```
# replace text in < > with your site name
cd ~/Kalabox/<your-site-name>
rm -rf code/

# Clone this or copy your own site code into the code directory
git clone https://github.com/ataylorme/advanced-wordpress-on-pantheon.git code
```

If you're using the Advanced WordPress install above, type the following lines, as well:

```
cd code/
./bin/local-build.sh
```

Make **certain** you added your code into the `~/Kalabox/<your-site-name>/code/` directory.

You can visit your site now at http://.kbox.site on your browser, but if you have a nested web root, you'll likely see an Nginx 500 error. This is the problem we're trying to fix!

## 4. Edit The Kalabox Setup to Allow A Nested Web Root

This part is the secret sauce. We have to get into the Docker container that Kalabox has setup and change the nginx configuration files. If all that sounds like non-sense to you, don't worry. These simple instructions should help you do it! Back to the terminal!

```
docker ps
```

This dumps a table with a list of the running Docker containers. Find the one that says `nginix` under the *Image* column. Look immediately to the left in the `Container ID` column. Note, copy and/or write down the first four-or-so letters of that container ID. You'll use those in the `<container-id>` part of this next command:

```
docker exec -i -t <container-id> bash
```

This opens a pseudo remote shell with your nginx container. Yay! Now we can edit the nginx files and get our site up-and-running! The command line probably changed a bit, showing your user as `root@<your-site-name>`. That means it worked.

The nginx container doesn't have a text editor downloaded by default. So, we'll download a tiny little text editor called Nano.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

Once those commands are finished running, we can edit the config file:

```
nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This opens the Nano editor with the configuration file we're trying to edit. Look and change the following lines:

```
# This one is near the top of the file
# Before
root /code;
# After
root /code/web;

# These next two are near the bottom of the file.
# This exact line appears twice--once in the `location ~ ^/simplesaml/`
# block, and once in the `location ~ \.php$` block. Edit it in
# BOTH locations.
#
# Before
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /code/$fastcgi_script_name;
# After
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /code/web/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

When you're done with that, type `<Ctrl-o> <Enter> <Ctrl-x>` to save your work and exit. You're back at the pseudo shell for your Docker container. Type `exit` to go back to your normal command line.

## 5. Rebuild Kalabox & Test It Out!

Make sure you're in the `~/Kalabox/<your-site-name>` directory, and type `kbox restart` just to make sure you've got everything cleared out of the Kalabox caches. Kalabox will stop and restart your site for you. Once it's done, visit http://.kbox.site in your browser to see your work!

## Extra Goodies

- Upgrade to PHP 7: Open `~/Kalabox/<your-site-name>/kalabox.yml` in your favorite editor, and change line 33 to `php: 70`.
- Remove `Undefined Index: NONCE_KEY` error: open `~/Kalabox/<your-site-name>/config/php/prepend.php` and go to roughly line 55 which reads `$_ENV['NONCE_SALT'] = getenv('NONCE_SALT');`. Below it, add a similar line: `$_ENV['NONCE_KEY'] = getenv('NONCE_KEY');`